# PL/SQL: SELECT INTO using a variable in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Code:

```
lc_tab1_col1 VARCHAR2(4000);
lc_tab1_col2 VARCHAR2(4000);
lc_tab2_col2 VARCHAR2(4000);
lc_tab2_col2 VARCHAR2(4000);
CURSOR my_cursor IS select col1, col2 from tab1;

[...]

    OPEN my_cursor;

       LOOP
       FETCH my_cursor INTO lc_tab1_col1, lc_tab1_col2;
       EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;

           SELECT lc_tab1_col2.col1, lc_tab1_col2.col2 INTO lc_tab2_col2, lc_tab2_col2 FROM lc_tab1_col2 WHERE lc_tab1_col2.col3 = lc_tab1_col1;


           [...]

       END LOOP;

    CLOSE my_cursor;
```

Hey folks,

I am trying to get the above code working.
The issue I am having is that a SELECT INTO statement apparently does not support using a variable (in that case `lc_tab1_col2`) as the table  name in the FROM clause of the statement.

When compiling the package an ORA-000942 is thrown (table or view does not exist), which tells me the variable is interpreted directly instead of being replaced and interpreted at runtime.

I can't think of a workaround on the fly, any ideas on how to fix this?

Some more background: `lc_tab1_col2` contains the name of a table in the database whereas `lc_tab1_col1` contains an ID.

This ID is present in all of the tables that can be contained in `lc_tab1_col2` (hence the WHERE clause).

Apart from the ID there are two other columns (`lc_tab1_col2.col1` and `lc_tab1_col2.col2`) that are present in all those tables, but that are not present in `tab1`. I need to select those two values to work with them inside the loop.

As there are many tables to consider, I need this SELECT INTO statement to be dynamic. It wouldn't be feasible to parse the tables one by one. Looking forward to anyone sharing a clever idea for overcoming this issue :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: for dynamic SQL you can use `execute immediate`. You can't provide table name from a variable directly

Comment: I  only used `execute immediate` to execute DDL statements up till now. Can you actually execute a SELECT statement with it and save the result to one (or more) variables?!

Comment: [Yes of course, see this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=execute-immediate-into-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you exception really means that this table does not exist or you don't have privileges to SELECT it.

I've executed a below code and everything was ok. I have tried to compile it in a package and also I didn't have any compilation errors

```
DECLARE 
  user_tables varchar2(30) := 'TBLCOMPANIES';
BEGIN
  SELECT table_name
    INTO user_tables 
    FROM user_tables
   WHERE user_tables.table_name = user_tables;

  dbms_output.put_line(user_tables) ;
END;
/
```